# Replicating a Backand instance automatically/using a script

Tags: backand

I'm using Backand as the api between my frontend and my externally hosted MySQL database.
This is a college project, and one of the requirements is to submit my project/code where my project must be deploy-able on the examiners server, from scratch.

Is there any way of setting up a Backand instance (on Backand.com) using a template of my current setup while modifying the specifics (database location, triggering a sync etc..)
I'm open to writing some bash scripts if necessary.

If anyone has any suggestions, I would love to hear them.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

[Backand](https://www.backand.com) logic run on Backand's server and can't be deployed on private server.

If it's simple logic, you can migrate it to [express](http://expressjs.com/)

Another possibility if it's in project rules, you can leave server side at Backand but deploy client code in many servers, and be able to serve more users from have your client code hosted on a single server.

Edit: You can export and import configuration in Backand see remarks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I'm not looking to setup an instance on my own server. I'm wondering is it possible to create an instance on backand.com, but through a script. Otherwise I'll need to share credentials with my exam board and possibly have to have them change the configuration by hand if they want to instanciate their own external database.

Comment: Do you want to duplicate your application?

Comment: yes ideally I want to be able to input specifics like the external MySQL database hostname and probably the owners credentials, and have it create a new instance of Backand from a template of mine. (I have come backups of my instance, so I feel like I'm already close)

Comment: Backand just add this new feature. You can export and import your configuration in settings > configuration tab. So you export form original app and import config to your new app. And after that you can change db configuration from DB tab.

Comment: I saw that! Perhaps I can write a simple script for creating a Backand user, project, import the config and change the database configuration. Thanks for the help @Ygalbel